# are iOS block parameters somehow allowed to be specific subclasses of defined type

Tags: ios, inheritance, objective-c-blocks

I've got a callback with a the following class hierarchy:

```
JSONCustomerObj : JSONObj
```

Here is the definition of the method with the generic JSONObj block parameter:

```
-(void) _getRemote:(NSString*) url callback:(void (^)(JSONObj *))callback{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:/*do operation extension of NSOperation*/];
}
```

Here are specific invocations of _getRemote:callback: with 2 failed attempts.

**OPTION # 1**

```
-(void) getCustomer:(void (^)(JSONCustomerObj *))cb{
    // I get a compile error
    [self _getRemote:@"www.a.com/json" callback:cb];
}
```

If I do the above^ I get a compile error. If I wrap and cast like below, I get a zombie crash (probably because my insitchu function wasn't retained).

**OPTION # 2**

```
-(void) getCustomer:(void (^)(JSONCustomerObj *))cb{
    // I get a runtime crash (non retained anonymous block?)
    [self _getRemote:@"www.a.com/json" callback:^(JSONObj* rsp){
       cb((JSONCustomerObj*)rsp);
    }];
}
```

Either option is invoked like the following

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[Services sharedInstance] getCustomer:^(JSONCustomerObj* obj){
        NSLog(@"name = %@",obj.name);
    }];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how the crash manifests (note that it actually DOES NSLog out but crashes shortly after:

[image: zombie crash]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `[self _getRemote:@"www.a.com/json" callback:(void (^)(JSONObj *))cb];` or `cb = [cb copy]; [self _getRemote:....]` for option 2

Comment: Yeah with both ideas I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS :(

Comment: can you show the complete error message and the line cause the problem? also, check `cb` the block is not null before call it.

Comment: that address `0xa1a1a1b1` looks like uninitialized variable to me, you should check `getCustomer`, it is different bug

Comment: Yes @BryanChen but the NSLog did print out the data. Something else is happening here. Incidentally the asynchronous activity is queued within NSOperation framework

Comment: "I get a zombie crash" You are getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, an actual segfault; not an exception thrown by messaging a zombie.

Comment: @newacct you will not get a neat NSException for messaging a zombie. A "bad access" by definition is the OS accessing a position and length in memory that no longer contains a complete object. It has been cleared or already repurposed by the OS. So I have to disagree with you.

Comment: @MikeS: isn't that exactly what I said? His bad access has nothing to do with zombies.

Comment: @newacct no you said EXC_BAD_ACCESS can never a zombie. You say zombie situations throw exceptions. I disagree on both points.

Comment: @MikeS: Okay, you are right on the second point. It prints a message to the console and signals SIGTRAP. It is true that it is never a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @newacct are you talking about it doing that when running instruments with zombies enabled?

Comment: @MikeS: no, with `NSZombieEnabled`

Comment: @newacct thats great and all - but with NSZombieEnabled=NO, (like I have set), you will get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS for a zombie

Comment: @MikeS: then you are not using zombies

Comment: @newacct Right I see what you are getting at. You are saying it shouldn't be termed a zombie unless NSZombieEnabled==YES. You may be right by the strict terms of the definition within the Xcode development tools framework.

Comment: @MikeS: Right, because segfaults can be caused by many things other than messaging a deallocated object. Particularly since there are blocks involved; for example, calling a nil block, or calling a stack block whose scope has ended, will also cause segfaults that can't be caught even if NSZombieEnabled=YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. Turns out (I think) my NSOperation subclass was garbage collected when the `main` method returned all while my callback block was being called asynchronously.

I fixed it like this; instead of calling completionCallbackBlock (which was in a property in my NSOperation subclass) at the end of my [NSOperation main] override, I used the `setCompletionBlock` function on NSOperation. Suddenly the crashing stopped. Here is what I ended up with.

```
    -(void) _runRequest:(NSString*) url complete:(void(^)(JSONObj *response)) complete{
    RequestOperation * operation = [[RequestOperation alloc] initWithURL:url];
    __weak RequestOperation * weakOperation = operation;
    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        complete(weakOperation.responseObject);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the exact definition of your method `_getRemote:callback:` and then cast your object like so :
`JSONCustomerObj *customer = (JSONCustomerObj *)rsp`

Comment: Sorry I poorly explained my issue. Please see updated question.

Comment: For option #2, block retains everything you are passing inside it so there's should not have any problem here. I don't know if it's simply a mistake in your copy/paste but there is a `*` missing here `cb((JSONCustomerObj)rsp);`. Despite this, this option might not be a good solution since you're return object is still a type of `JSONObj` and so will not responding to any `JSONCustomerObj` methods. You may then considering creating a new `JSONCustomerObj` from a `JSONObj` and then pass it in the parameter of the block

Comment: The magic in _getRemote does instantiate the correct class (JSONCustomerObj) since elsewhere I pass around a Class object. I don't think that is relevant to this, but it could be. See my updated question with more details - might help.